# Google cloud storage file stream into fsReadstream without saving to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, google-cloud-storage

I need to send a video file from google cloud storage to an api, this api normally accepts fs filestreams. However this means I have to save the video file by downloading it and saving it to a file locally before sending it. I'd really like to avoid that if possible.

This is how I'm currently sending my video files to the api, it expects a fs readstream.

```
            const filestream = fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/[me]/Downloads/testvid.mp4');
            data.append('video',filestream);
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: postUrl,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    ...data.getHeaders()
                },
                data: data
            })
```

What I'd like to do is essentially grab the file from the storage bucket create a readstream out of it WITHOUT saving it locally and pass it onto my axios post request.

```
            const file = await storage.bucket("[bucket]").file("filename.mp4");
            fs.createReadStream(file);
```

How would I accomplish this?

So far I've tried passing the google read stream into it directly, and created a passthrough stream by importing 'stream' but neither have worked.
I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: Were you able to check my answer?

Comment: @Alex My solution works very similarly to yours I'll add it as a separate answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Download objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-nodejs) page, you can see at the bottom a link to [Create transfers](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-transfers#file-system) using different sources and destinations like Cloud Storage or file system.

If this is not what you want to do, you can use or combine it with [Streaming transfers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming). There is a good example  of [download streams using Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#stream_a_download) as follows:

```js
/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
// The ID of your GCS bucket
// const bucketName = 'your-unique-bucket-name';

// The ID of your GCS file
// const fileName = 'your-file-name';

// The filename and file path where you want to download the file
// const destFileName = '/local/path/to/file.txt';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function streamFileDownload() {
  // The example below demonstrates how we can reference a remote file, then
  // pipe its contents to a local file.
  // Once the stream is created, the data can be piped anywhere (process, sdout, etc)
  await storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .file(fileName)
    .createReadStream() //stream is created
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destFileName))
    .on('finish', () => {
      // The file download is complete
    });

  console.log(
    `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName} downloaded to ${destFileName}.`
  );
}

streamFileDownload().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed a solution similar to what Alex suggested but instead of getting everything from Google directly I just used a get request on Google's URL to get a stream and passed that onto my `formdata` as a stream. This works perfectly with so I can send a file from a remote server without downloading it.

```
const downStream = await axios({ method: 'GET', responseType: 'stream', url: url })
var data: FormData = new FormData();
data.append('video', downStream.data);
const response = await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: postUrl,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data: data,
  maxContentLength: Infinity,
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working like so:

```
import FormData from 'form-data'; // npm install form-data

const uploadFileFromCloudStorage = async (bucketName, fileName) => {
   const file = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName);

   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', file.createReadStream(), fileName);

   const res = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: postUrl,
      headers: { ...myAuthHeaders, ...formData.getHeaders() },
      data: formData
   });
};
```

Haven't yet tested with a video, but works for images.