# GCS download attempt results in "cannot read property of null" on state.buffer[0].length

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to download a Google Cloud Storage object to `/tmp` in a Google Cloud Run service running Node.js. I followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/image-processing) and have the following code:

```js
exports.resizeImage = async (eventData) => {
  const file = storage.bucket(eventData.bucket).file(eventData.name);

  // Resolve the image extension
  const [metadata] = await file.getMetadata();
  const extension = metadataContentTypeToExtension(metadata.contentType);

  const tempLocalPath = `/tmp/${path.parse(file.name).base}.${extension}`;

  console.log(tempLocalPath); // Prints "/tmp/clpeytui4003nfcsjqjyifk0d.jpg"

  try {
    // This is just for testing to see if I'm pointing at the object correctly
    const url = await file.getSignedUrl({
      action: 'read',
      expires: '03-17-2025',
    });
    console.log(`Here's an access URL: ${url}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Unable to get presigned URL:');
    console.error(err);
  }

  // Download file from bucket.
  try {
    console.log(`Downloading ${file.name} to ${tempLocalPath}...`);
    const dlPromise = file.download({ destination: tempLocalPath });
    dlPromise.catch((err) => {
      console.error('Download failed (caught in promise catch).');
      console.error(err);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`File download failed: ${err}`);
    return;
  }
```

This is what I get in the Cloud Run logs:
[image: Cloud Run logs]

The presigned URL works if I copy and paste it into my browser, so I'm pretty sure I'm targeting the file properly. I've also given the service the `storage.admin` role (since it was complaining about not being able to list the bucket contents at one point), so I *think* I've given it the permissions it needs...

From what I can tell, the service/code seems to be having trouble getting a data stream to download the file, but I'm not sure if that's the problem. I tried specifying my own download function to see if it was a GCS library bug:

```js
const downloadFile = (file, downloadPath) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Attempting to download file...');
    file
      .createReadStream()
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(downloadPath))
      .on('finish', () => {
        console.log(`Image downloaded locally to ${downloadPath}`);
        console.log(`File size: ${fs.statSync(downloadPath).size} bytes`);
        resolve();
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('Failed to download file.', err);
        reject(err);
      });
  });
```

but I get the same error in the same underlying `stream-shift` call, so I guess that's just what Node uses.

It is strange that I'm not seeing any of my custom error messages anywhere...

**EDIT 11/26:** I replaced the `.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(downloadPath))` call with my own implementation of handling the incoming data (storing it in memory), and everything magically worked.

```js
const downloadFile = (file, downloadPath) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const buffer = [];
    file
      .createReadStream()
      // .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(downloadPath)) // Problematic line
      .on('data', (chunk) => {
        buffer.push(chunk);
      })
      .on('finish', () => {
        fs.writeFileSync(downloadPath, Buffer.concat(buffer));
        resolve();
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('Failed to download file.', err);
        reject(err);
      });
  });
```

(I verified the data was coming through and being saved correctly by uploading the downloaded file to another GCS bucket and it was indeed the same photo I'd originally uploaded to the first bucket.)

So it seems that there's some problem with the writing of a stream as opposed to a buffer. I just don't understand why the Google-provided code doesn't handle writing the incoming stream properly...

Comment: Here is the GitHub issue for the GCS node library: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/2368

Comment: Aha, thanks for sharing that @MattPalmerlee! If you want to add that as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across this issue.

The stream-shift library has an update, however the library using it, duplexify looks unmaintained. Duplexify looks like its used by the Google Storage Lib.

The problem appears to be the use of streams in stream-shift when using NodeJS 20.11<

You might be able to fix the original behaviour by including the following snippet in your package.json

```
"dependancies": { ... },
"overrides": {
    "stream-shift": "1.0.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" error occurs when accessing the length property on an undefined value. To solve the error, make sure to only access the length property on data types that support it - arrays and strings.Check if the value is of the correct type before accessing length.

You can also check if the value is of the correct type before accessing the length property.

`//Check if array before accessing length if (Array.isArray(value)) {   const result = value.length;   console.log(result); } else {   console.log('The value is NOT an array'); }`

`// Check if string before accessing length if (typeof value === 'string') {   const result = value.length;   console.log(result); } else {   console.log('The value is NOT a string'); }`

Check this helpful official documentation for [Streaming download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming-downloads#stream_a_download) .

Also check these links which have similar implementations discussed:

1. [GCS filestream into fsreadstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72605933/google-cloud-storage-file-stream-into-fsreadstream-without-saving-to-file)
2. [Node.js streams read and write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60822895/node-js-confusion-about-buffers-streams-pipe-axios-createwritestream-and-cr)
3. [How to read streams file from GCS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275856/how-to-read-file-from-google-cloud-storage)

**#Update**

@mightimaus As per your edit

> EDIT 11/26: I replaced the .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(downloadPath)) call….

It seems you have resolved the issue. glad to know that the issue is solved. And also you have commented below in your edit.

> So it seems that there's some problem with the writing of a stream as opposed to a buffer. I just don't understand why the Google-provided code doesn't handle writing the incoming stream properly..

It might be an issue on the documentation side or the example code provided.For me it seems you can file an issue at  [Official github page for cloud storage in Node JS](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/issues)

Comment: The error is coming from the `stream-shift` library code, which I'm not calling directly, so I can't change how any of that underlying code works. I'm just calling `storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download({ destination: tmpPathToUse })`, which is just calling functions from the `@google-cloud/storage` package.

Comment: See my latest edit to my original post

Comment: @mightimaus, I have updated my answer please have a look.